# How do you using the mapply function to create random draws from a dataset?

Tags: r, function, random, mapply

I currently have a random bunch numbers listed from -1billion to positive 1 billion in a dataset, that is all. I want to write a function so that it will pull 5 random numbers 100,000 times from the dataset and then see how many times the number is below 0. Can I use the mapply function for this? or would another function be better.

The dataset is called numbers as has 2 columns, with the column i want to pull the numbers from called listofnumbers.

Currently i have a for loop but it seems to take forever to run, the code is below

````
    ```
    n=5
    m=100000

    base_table <- as_tibble (0)

    for (j in 1:m)
    {
    for (i in 1:n)
    {
    base_table[i,j] <- as_tibble(sample_n(numbers, 1) %>% pull(listofnumbers))
    }
    } 
    ```
````

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reduced size example:

```
r <- -100:100
n <- 10
collect <- 1000
output <- replicate(collect, sum(sample(r, n) < 0))
hist(output)
```

You would simply replace `r`, `n` and `collect` with your values.  I.e., r = `numbers$listofnumbers`, n = 5, collect = 100000